# What type of Jyotish do Shaktas use?

Tags: astrology, durga, shaktism, kali, sri-vidya

Vaishnavas are known to follow Bhrigu and Lomasha Jyotish.
Shaivas follow Shiva Jyotish.
Smartas, and sometimes Vaishnavas with Shaivas, follow Parashara Jyotish.

And what type of Jyotish is followed in the Tripurasundari, Durga and Kali sampradayas?

I heard that they use standard Jyotish, but build a natal chart from Arudha Lagna... Although if you follow Gauri Jataka, they should build a horoscope from the Moon, but this is just my guess.